# package android.support.v7.internal.widget does not exist and package AdapterViewCompat does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After switching to API - 24, and updating a few Gradle dependencies, I got several errors. I do not know what could be going on. Any ideas?
 Here is my Build.Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo/' }
}

android {
flavorDimensions "analytics"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

productFlavors {
    withAnalytics {
        dimension "analytics"
    }
    noAnalytics {
        dimension "analytics"
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.marlonjones.Ravynproject"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1 Internal Testing"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'qksms-proguard.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'qksms-proguard.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    // Use Java 1.7, requires minSdk 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false

    // Translations are crowd-sourced
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}

}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
}
```

}

```
String leakCanaryVersion = '1.4-beta2'

dependencies {
// Open source libraries
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.pushbullet:android-extensions:1.0.4'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-chips:1.0.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:6.2'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.6'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0'
debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leakCanaryVersion"
releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leakCanaryVersion"
compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:3.1.3'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.6'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.1.7'
compile 'org.ligi:snackengage:0.4'
compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

// Google libraries
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
withAnalyticsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'

// External services
withAnalyticsCompile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

}

Errors: package android.support.v7.internal.widget does not exist and package AdapterViewCompat does not exist

Comment: You need to configure the Support Library correctly in gradle by adding the correct lines to `dependencies`.

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:24.2.0'` Does it work?

Comment: update buildTools to '24.0.2'

Comment: I added the support Library in Dependencies, and updated build tools. None of those worked and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the appcompat **`v.23.2.0`** the `android.support.v7.internal` package was removed.

It is an internal package and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: What should I replace it with then?